# Cleaning survey data - pair of similar questions in each column

Tags: r, tidyr, tidyverse

I have a messy dataset (from CATI survey). I am a struggling to prepare and tidy it because of interviewee /partner/child files, deal with doublet (pair of similar questions) in each column

For example a chunk of data for gender is look like this **(1 = male , 2 = female)**

```
# A tibble: 7 x 7
  Household_size    q_1   q_2   q_3   q_4   q_5   q_6 
  <int>            <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 3                  1     2     1     NA   NA    NA
2 2                  2     1     NA    NA   NA    NA
3 5                  1     2     1     1    2     NA
4 3                  2     2     1     NA   NA    NA
5 6                  2     1     1     1    1     1
6 5                  1     2     1     2    2     NA
7 3                  1     2     2     NA   NA    NA
```

Metadata says :

> ```
> q_1 is  interviewee gender
> q_2 is  interviewee - partner gender (if there is any)
> q_3:q_6 interviewee - kid gender     (if there is any)
> ```

The data has the same format for education, occupation etc (pair of identical questions for interviewee /partner/kid).

How can I tidy up this dataset to be able to easily calculate statistical summary or visualization. I would like to have something like this(total number of male and female in the survey regardless of age):

```
Male    15
Female  12
```

Comment: Can you add which q's correspond to which genders?

Comment: @camille This is a telephone interviewing survey. q_1 is the number owner ( interviewee) gender (are you male or female --- 1 = male , 2 = female), q_2 is his/her partner gender ( (is he/she) male or female), q_3:q_6 is his/her child gender (again, (is he/she) male or female)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `table` function in base R might be what you are looking for, it gives you a versatile option which counts all the levels:

```
table(unlist(df1[,c(2:7)]))
```

Alter this to make the dataframe name (`df1`) and column numbers `c(2,7)` suit your needs.

This replicates your example too:

```
df1 <- data.frame("v" = LETTERS[1:7], "q1" = c(1,2,1,2,2,1,1), "q2" = c(2,1,2,2,1,2,2), "q3" = c(1,NA,1,1,1,1,2), "q4" = c(NA, NA,1,NA,1,2,NA), "q5" = c(NA, NA,2,NA,1,2,NA), "q6" = c(NA, NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA))

> table(unlist(df1[,c(2:7)]))
 1  2 
15 12
```

Some more examples:

```
df1 <- data.frame("v" = LETTERS[1:5], "q1" = c(1,2,6,1,1), "q2" = c("k","k","f","h","p"), "q3" = c(1,2,NA,1,NA))

> df1
  v q1 q2 q3
1 A  1  k  1
2 B  2  k  2
3 C  6  f NA
4 D  1  h  1
5 E  1  p NA 

table(unlist(df1[,c(2,4)]))
table(unlist(df1[,3]))

> table(unlist(df1[,c(2,4)]))
1 2 6 
5 2 1 

> table(unlist(df1[,3]))
f h k p 
1 1 2 1
```

Comment: For example for the first row : the owner is male (q_1 = 1) , his partner is female (q_2 = 2) , having just one child  - male (boy)  (q_3 = 1) so for this observation we have 2 male and 1 female and so on

Comment: That is understood, it just sounds from your q that this might not be the only summary you want. Table is probably your best option in any case. Define the columns you want to count up in the square brackets: `c(2,7)` is telling it to count the occurrences of each level in those columns. If this works please accept the answer, if not, please clarify the question

Comment: You are perfectly correct, it is not the only summary I want. I will try with your suggestion and camille one and get back to you shortly. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

It's straightforward if you put the data into a long format, filter out the `NA`s, make gender into a factor, and tally up the counts. I'm using `fct_recode` from `forcats` (ships with `tidyverse`), but you can also change the labels of factor levels in base R.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
    gather(key = person, value = gender, -Household_size) %>%
    filter(!is.na(gender)) %>%
    mutate(gender_fct = as.factor(gender) %>% forcats::fct_recode("Male" = "1", "Female" = "2")) %>%
    count(gender_fct)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   gender_fct     n
#>   <fct>      <int>
#> 1 Male          15
#> 2 Female        12
```

Created on 2018-05-05 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).